# machine learning - check & parse sentence related to previous sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, named-entity-recognition

During natural language processing, what should be the logic to determine if the current sentence has "cues" which needs to be taken from the previous sentence while parsing.

I am not sure how to aptly describe this issue or what sub-topic of NLP it is referred as, so I would present an example.

If *previous sentence* was `Find me an Italian restaurant in New York city`
and the *current sentence* is `What's the weather there tomorrow`

How should the parser proceed to understand that `there` in the current sentence refers to `New york` which was mentioned in the previous sentence.

*PS - I am fairly new to NLP, so please be kind here with your explanations.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anaphor is an expression that refers back to a previous expression in a natural language discourse. For example: "Mary died. She was very old." The word **she** refers to **Mary**, and is described as an **anaphoric reference** to Mary. Mary is described as the **antecedent** of she. Anaphoric references are frequently pronouns, as in the example, but may also be definite noun phrases, as in: "Ronald Reagan frowned. The President was clearly worried by this issue." Here The President is an anaphoric reference to Ronald Reagan. Anaphors may in some cases not be explicitly mentioned in a previous sentence - as in "John got out his pencil. He found that the lead was broken." The lead here refers to a subpart of his pencil. Anaphors need not be in the immediately preceding sentence, they could be further back, or in the same sentence, as in "John got out his pencil, but found that the lead was broken." In all our examples so far the anaphor and the antecedent are noun phrases, but VP and sentence-anaphora is also possible, as in "I have today dismissed the prime minister. It was my duty in the circumstances." Here It is an anaphoric reference to the VP dismissed the prime minister.
For a fairly complete and quite entertaining treatment of anaphora, see [Hirst, G. Anaphora in Natural Language Understanding: A Survey Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science 119, Berlin: Springer, 1981](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/pub/gh/Hirst-Anaphora-0.pdf).

You can also find an algorithm to solve the problem in this [Paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Y99-1027).

Comment: This actually got me started where to look at. While digging around, I found the term `coreference`. Can they be said to be completely related?

Comment: Coreference resolution is the task of finding all expressions that refer to the same entity in a text. It is an important step for a lot of higher level NLP tasks that involve natural language understanding such as document summarization, question answering, and information extraction.